# Limiting Returns by Day with SQL DB2

Tags: sql, odbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to run a report that will only return results between the previous day and the first day of the week.  I have tried accomplishing this a couple of different ways, and so far have been unsuccessful.  I have code that works with Access (listed below) but I am trying to run the query without Access.  Here is what I have thus far.

```
--This does not work
DB1.TB1.DATE_ID Between (current day-1 day) And current day='MONDAY'

--This will work in Access
DB1.TB1.DATE_ID=201302) AND ((Weekday([DATE_ID])) Between 2 And Weekday(Date()-1)))
```

Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The DB2 SQL Cookbook might be of use to you: http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/id1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of DAYOFWEEK function which returns an integer value for days i.e. 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday.

so `DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT DATE) - 1 DAYS` will return number of days which can be subtracted from current day to get the Monday of current week.

Here is the exact statement:

```
CURRENT DATE - ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT DATE) - 1 ) DAYS
```

Comment: Ok, so how would I utilize this to pull data between current day -1 and Monday.  Each time the report is run they want a week to date total.  So if today is Wednesday, they would want returns including Monday and Tuesday.  If today is Friday, they would want Monday Through Thursday.

Comment: I apologize for being a little dense.  Your solution worked perfectly.  Thank you!